# sum every element of 2 dimensional list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2 dimensional list like this :

```
list1 = [[2,4,6,8,9],[8,9,10,12,15],[8,9,4,20,25]]
```

I want to sum every element of every row with another row and outcome is like this:

```
outcome_list = [[10,13,16,20,24],[16,18,14,32,40],[10,13,20,28,34]]
```

My code is this:

```
d = len(list1) 

for i in range(0, d-1):
    list2 = list[i][:] + list[i+1][:]
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pair the sub-lists by zipping the list with itself but with the items rotated to the right, and `map` the pairs to the `operator.add` method in a list comprehension:

```
from operator import add
[list(map(add, *p)) for p in zip(list1, list1[1:] + list1[:1])]
```

This returns:

```
[[10, 13, 16, 20, 24], [16, 18, 14, 32, 40], [10, 13, 10, 28, 34]]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Can you trying saying it in a different way?

Comment: i mean that when sum 2 element then  divide 2 and then print the outcome

Comment: list = [[2,4,6],[[8,10,12],[14,16,18]] and now my outcome should be outcome = [[5,7,9],[11,13,15],[8,10,12]]

Comment: You can do: `[[(a + b) // 2 for a, b in zip(*p)] for p in zip(list1, list1[1:] + list1[:1])]`

Answer (score 1):

That can be done like:

#### Code:

```
list1 = [[2, 4, 6, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10, 12, 15], [8, 9, 4, 20, 25]]

print([[sum(l) for l in zip(list1[i], list1[(i+1) % len(list1)])]
       for i in range(len(list1))])
```

#### Results:

```
[[10, 13, 16, 20, 24], [16, 18, 14, 32, 40], [10, 13, 10, 28, 34]]
```

Comment: with this when my list1 become bigger the code product repetitious outcome!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with a list-comprehension:

```
list1 = [[2,4,6,8,9],[8,9,10,12,15],[8,9,4,20,25]]

list1 = list1 + [list1[0]]
print([list(map(lambda x: sum(x), zip(x, y))) for x, y in zip(list1, list1[1:])])

# [[10, 13, 16, 20, 24], [16, 18, 14, 32, 40], [10, 13, 10, 28, 34]]
```

Comment: my list1 has 40 row and when run your code give the error list  index out of range !!!! have you any idea ????

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d = len(list1) 

for i in range(0, d-1):
    list2 = [a + b for a,b in zip(list[i],list[i+1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[2,4,6,8,9],[8,9,10,12,15],[8,9,4,20,25]])

In [3]: a + np.roll(a, -1, axis=0)
Out[3]:
array([[10, 13, 16, 20, 24],
       [16, 18, 14, 32, 40],
       [10, 13, 10, 28, 34]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way to do it using itertools which should work for any number of lists in list1:

```
from itertools import combinations
list1   = [[2,4,6,8,9],[8,9,10,12,15],[8,9,4,20,25]]
outcome = [ list(map(sum,zip(*rows))) for rows in combinations(list1,2) ]
```

Comment: otherList += outcome  (has to be a list of list as well though)